# Al agregar la referencia del servicio web no me recupera todas las propiedades de un objeto

Tags: vb.net, webservice

Estoy utilizando VB.Net en Visual Studio 2012. Para un proyecto tengo que utilizar un servicio web (el de preproducción de RAEE) del cual no tengo posibilidad de cambiar nada. El problema es que parece que en VB no me genera todos los atributos que debería generar.

Lo tengo añadido como referencia de servicio. Según el XSD, la clase collectionRAEEDataType debería incluir propiedades como receiver, referenceNumber, sigCode. Pero, al ir a acceder desde VB a ellas, hay dos que no me muestra: sigCode y responsabilitySystemData.

He contactado con el correo de soporte del servicio web y me dicen que sí, que en el servicio en Java la clase está generada con esos campos:

```
public class CollectionRAEEDataType {
protected String sigCode;
protected RegisteredInfoDataType responsabilitySystemData;
...
}
```

Pero desde VB, en el Reference.vb, me aparece esto:

```
Partial Public Class collectionRAEEDataType
        Inherits Object
        Implements System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged

        Private itemField As Object

        Private receiverField As receiverType

        Private referenceNumberField As String

        Private assignmentOfficeIdField As String

        '''<remarks/>
        <System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("responsabilitySystemData", GetType(registeredInfoDataType), Form:=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, Order:=0),  _
         System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("sigCode", GetType(collectionRAEEDataTypeSigCode), Form:=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, Order:=0)>  _
        Public Property Item() As Object
            Get
                Return Me.itemField
            End Get
            Set
                Me.itemField = value
                Me.RaisePropertyChanged("Item")
            End Set
        End Property

        '''<remarks/>
        <System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()>  _
        Public Property receiver() As receiverType
            Get
                Return Me.receiverField
            End Get
            Set
                Me.receiverField = value
                Me.RaisePropertyChanged("receiver")
            End Set
        End Property
...
```

Donde se ve que la propiedad receiver sí se ha obtenido bien, pero responsabilitySystemData y sigCode no se han traducido en propiedades.

Los de soporte me han dicho que "Respecto al problema que os ocurre lamentamos no poder ayudaros, es algún tema de Visual que desconocemos, no utilizamos esa tecnología". Con lo que no han servido de mucha ayuda.

¿Podríais aportar algo de luz en esto? ¿Quizá tenga alguna configuración mal hecha o algo así y por eso no me coge bien los atributos?

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Me respondo yo mismo. Tenía que instanciar el campo Item con el tipo que quisiera darle, según la definición del xsd.

Muchas gracias.